# KQL skip join if table is empty

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I have two tables, and I want to join `table1` with `table2`. But in case `table2` is empty, return just `table1` without the join.

```
let table1 = datatable (col1: int, col2: string)
[
    1, "A",
    2, "B",
    3, "C"
];
let table2 = datatable (col1: int, col3: string)
[
    1, "X",
    2, "Y"
    // If table2 is empty, comment out the above two lines
];
let isEmpty = toscalar(table2 | count | project isempty = Count == 0);
table1
| join kind=inner (table2) on col1
```

For example in this scenario, I want to get

| col1 | col2 | col11 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | X |
| 2 | B | 1 | Y |

But if `table2` is empty, get the entire `table1`:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

How can I do that?

Comment: Change the `join type` from `inner` to `leftouter`.

Comment: @Aswin `leftouter` leaves the entire `table1` even if `table2` is **not** empty

Comment: Left outer join will return the entire table1 data and give the matching records from table2. [Demo_with_left_join](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32QywrCMBBF9%2FmKS1cWCtq6U7pQceEfKOIi1lGjaSLNqAj9eKe1BRdiVifM5czDEoP13lKKHAfNuv1gUHibTmAcJxDMJghcGXeK1VZBXpogmkVJy5nwvOOx8CJSu6myvTj7Jx7%2FEq%2B%2FxJuoxeEQq2PvMwFU3vjVGMqSHMPfpdmZoPf%2BQeCnhzWOQj%2BHCcsmL4OwD4W2uhp0qloUdxHUuFX%2BQkWTpS67aCt5jlE8VZ8bqRoXbxyuxh1yS0eWxlQBnS6Gd81W6Ru5jcujVgEAAA%3D%3D). If you have different issue, can you give explain with more data.This may help to understand scenario.

Comment: @Aswin I edited the question and add examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have two tables, and I want to join `table1` with `table2`. But in case `table2` is empty, return just `table1` without the join.

To achieve your desired output, try the code below, where I used the `union` operator on a **Table1** and an `inner` join to check whether there is an empty table or not.

```sql
let table1 = datatable (col1: int, col2: string)
[
    1, "A",
    2, "B",
    3, "C"
];

let table2 = datatable (col1: int, col3: string)[];

let isEmpty = toscalar(table2 | count | project isempty = Count == 0);

let func1= view(){
table1
};

let func2 = view(){
table1
| join kind=inner (table2) on col1
};

union (func1() | where isEmpty), (func2() | where not(isEmpty))
```

In the above case as the **Table2** is empty, it prints the data present in the **Table1**.

**Output:**

```
Col1    Col2    
  1       A       
  2       B
  3       C
```

While **Table2** is not empty:

```sql
let table1 = datatable (col1: int, col2: string)
[
    1, "A",
    2, "B",
    3, "C"
];

let table2 = datatable (col1: int, col3: string)
[
    1,"K"
];

let isEmpty = toscalar(table2 | count | project isempty = Count == 0);

let func1= view(){
table1
};

let func2 = view(){
table1
| join kind=inner (table2) on col1
};

union (func1() | where isEmpty), (func2() | where not(isEmpty))
```

In this case as the **Table2** consists of data, it uses `inner` join and prints the common data from both the tables as you can see in the below output:
**Output:**

```
Col1    Col2    Col1    Col3
  1       A       1       K
```